# How to open a drawer on click of a bottom tab in React Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation. I have a 'more' button as the last item of the bottom tab navigator and I want it to open a drawer when a user clicks on it. I have tried so many things and studied so many answers but nothing works. The closest I can get is below. It brings you to a page which contains a drawer that can be opened. However, I want it to be opened when it is clicked.

So far I have this code...

```
const MoreStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  More: { screen: More }
})

const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack }
    ...
    More: { screen: MoreStack }
})

const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    MainTabNavigator: MainTabNavigator,
})

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
  Home: { screen: MainStackNavigator }
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator)
```

**UPDATE**

So a possible solution is to open the MoreStack with an initial Route that renders a FlatList as opposed to a drawer. In the MoreStack I also create all the pages I need to be included in the More FlatList. Then in the More screen I create an array with each route as an object and I link to them from the FlatList using navigation.navigate(item.name)

The problem with this, and the key to making it work like a drawer was setting the backBehavior: 'history', in the MainTabNavigator. Then, when you add a gesture handler to the 'More' screen onSwipeRight and set to navigation.goBack(null) it will return you to the previous route, making it feel like you are 'closing' the more screen.

I am not sure how this will all work once I get into more navigation situations for routes within the MoreStack, but I guess I'll deal with that when I get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your tab navigator and StackNavigator should be the MainTabNavigator s child as:

```
           const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
                   Home: { screen: HomeStack }

                   More: { screen: MoreStack }
           })             

           const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
              MainTabNavigator: MainTabNavigator,
            })

           const MoreStack = createDrawerNavigator({
              SomePage:{screen:MainTabNavigator}//<<<<<<<<
               SomeOther:{screen:MainStackNavigator}//<<<<<<<<<<
               More: { screen: More }

               })

           const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
           Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
           Home: { screen: MaoreStack }//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
             })
```

and then give MoreStack to AppSwitchNavigator.....

Comment: I am getting 'Component for route SomePage must be a react component.' I think because MainStackNavigator and MainTabNavigator are beneath MoreStack. When I put them above MoreStack I get 'can't find variable MainTabNavigator'

Comment: ok I will edit the answer check it plz. just change your object creating order will fix it... i should create MainTabNavigator before moreStack

Comment: This doesn't work either. I then get the message 'Component for route More must be a react component'

Comment: Ps - I have also tried separating out each function and importing them and that still creates the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I used the 3.x version of react-navigation

```
const FooterTabs = (props) => (
 <Footer>
  <FooterTab}>
     <Button
       vertical
       onPress={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
      <Text style={styles.Text}> Menu</Text>
     </Button>
   </FooterTab>
  </Footer>
 )
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack }
    ...
    More: { screen: MoreStack }
},{
tabBarComponent: props =>
  <FooterTabs
    {...props} />,
initialRouteName: "Home",
})

const MoreStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  More: { screen: More }
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MoreStack )
```